# Import font, straight integral symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols, math-operators, math-fonts, integral

I tried a lot (2 days) and try to find a way to extend a answer

[Using XITS with pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304656/using-xits-with-pdflatex)

but I am unable to understand the method here. How do I extend above answer 
to include vertical closed integrals like '\oint'

I have been using straight vertical integral symbols so far and now I need closed integral. How do I do that

[image]

Comment: Does the use of `\usepackage[upint]{stix}` not produce the vertical closed integrals?  If so, that appears to be a bug, and should be reported.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It does work, but it changes all other fonts in my documents which I do not want. I just want the integrals to change.

Comment: Okay.  You want just the vertical integrals from `stix`.  Then you might try the techniques shown in one of these questions: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386) or [How to get only one symbol from a symbol package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174814).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thats what I have been reading and trying since two days but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried `\setmathfont[StylisticSet=8]{XITS Math}`?

Comment: I suppose you don’t mean `\ointup`, or `\let\oint\ointup`, right? Maybe you could what you want by giving a small piece of your code.

Comment: Added a version that properly supports both display and text style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304657/53795) you gave yourself, I suppose this is what you’re looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{integrals}{LS2}{stixcal}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointupop}{\mathop}{integrals}{"B2}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\oint}{\DOTSI\ointupop\ilimits@}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[
  \oint
\]
\end{document}
```

You can find the definitions of the character code point (*e.g.*, `B2` for `\oint`) in `tex/latex/stix/stix.sty` in your LaTeX distribution.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5):

### The Easy Way

As egreg wrote, the easy answer is to `\usepackage[upint]{stix}`.  XITS is a fork of the STIX font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upint]{stix}

\begin{document}
\[ \int \oint \oiint \iint \iiint \]
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX upint sample]

### The Complicated Way

If you want to add individual symbols the legacy way, you need to look up in [the package documantation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf) which slot of which font they are in.  The symbol you are looking for is on page 39, in slot "E8 of font `stix-mathcal`.  Then you open up the file `stix.sty` and reverse-engineer the necessary setup for that symbol font.

Since there are two versions of the symbol, a display-style one in slot "E8 and a smaller one at "B2, you in fact would want to select between them with `\mathchoice`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{integrals}{LS2}{stixcal}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointupbig}{\mathop}{integrals}{"E8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointupsmall}{\mathop}{integrals}{"B2}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ointup}{\mathchoice{\ointupbig}{\ointupsmall}{\ointupsmall}{\ointupsmall}}

\begin{document}
\( \displaystyle
   \oint_{\oint_{\oint}} \quad
   \ointup_{\ointup_{\ointup}} \)

\( \oint \quad
   \ointup \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Sloped and upright <code>\oint</code> in the same document]

I do not recommend this, as it depends on fiddly little implementation details of the `stix` package, runs into the limit on legacy math alphabets, and has other quirks.

But, I think that was what you were asking how to do?

### The Modern Way

You can also do this with `unicode-math`, and I recommend that unless you are forced to submit to a site that does not yet support LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

If you want to use XITS Math as your math font, you can load it with

```
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=8]{XITS Math}
```

If you want to use the XITS upright integrals together with another font, you can add the command

```
\setmathfont[range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C},StylisticSet=8]{XITS Math}
```

after you load your main `\setmathfont`.  This also works with STIX Two Math.  If you’re mixing different math fonts with different heights, you might want to add the `Scale=MatchUppercase` font option.

Comment: @Davisior Thanks for the answer. I can not use unicode-math as I am using pdflatex, or stix package it changes all the fonts. I found the way I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`wasysym.sty` is one of the easiest way and the `MWE` (as you didn't provide any `MWE`, so I gave suggestion based on the standard template) is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[integrals]{wasysym}
\begin{document}

\[
\int
\]

\end{document}
```